# Which property of THEMES/CLARO.CSS inside DOJO TOOLKIT shows the text box inside the buttons DIJIT/FORM/BUTTON?

Tags: dojo

Which property of THEMES/CLARO.CSS inside DOJO TOOLKIT shows the text box inside the buttons DIJIT/FORM/BUTTON ??

[image: buttons]

I would like to remove the black box from the text and icon.
Change the "baseClass" button but it still persists.
Configure the following:

```
 .button0 {
     margin: 2px;
     padding: 3px;
     background-color: #ffec64;
     border-radius: 9px;
     border: 3px solid #ffaa22;
 }
 .button0:hover {
     background-color: #ffaa22;
 }
```

And add "button0" to "baseClass" of widget.

Answer (score 0):

I found the class that had the box and was able to get it out:

```
.dijitButtonNode {
    border: 0px;
}
```